# WIll the stack pointer in the function would be formal parameter?

Tags: c++, c, stack

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

struct node

{

  int data;

  struct node *next;

};



struct stack

{

node *head;

};

void push(struct stack *stack1,int data)
{

   struct node *new_node= new node;

   new_node->data=data;

   if(stack1->head!=NULL)

   new_node->next=stack1->head;

   else

    new_node->next=NULL;

    stack1->head=new_node;

 }


void pop(struct stack *stack1)

{  

  node *temp= new node;

  if(stack1->head==NULL)

   cout<<"EMPTY"<<endl;

   else

   {

     temp=stack1->head;

     stack1->head=(stack1->head)->next;

     int t;

     t=temp->data;

     free(temp);

     cout<<t<<" ";

   }

}



void show(struct stack *stack1)

{

  node *new_node=new node;

  new_node=stack1->head;

   if(stack1->head==NULL)

  {

    cout<<"EMPTY"<<endl;

    return;

  }

   while(new_node!=NULL)

  {

     cout<<new_node->data<<" ";

     new_node=new_node->next;

  }

}



void peek(struct stack *stack1)

{

   if(stack1->head==NULL)

   cout<<"EMPTY";

   else

   cout<<stack1->head->data<<" ";

}





int main()

{

  int temp,temp2;

  struct stack *stack1=new stack;

  stack1->head=NULL;

  while(1)

  { 

     cin>>temp;

     switch(temp) 

   {

     case 0: exit(0);



     case 1: cin>>temp2;

             cout<<endl;

             push(stack1,temp2);

             break;



     case 2: pop(stack1);

             cout<<endl;

             break;



     case 3: peek(stack1);

             cout<<endl;

             break;



     case 4: show(stack1);

             cout<<endl;

             break;

   }

  }

  return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ Standard

> 1.3.14 [defns.parameter]
>
> parameter formal argument
>   **formal parameter**
>
> object or reference declared as part of a
>   function declaration or definition or in the catch clause of an
>   exception handler that acquires a value on entry to the function or
>   handler

From the C Standard

> 3.16 1 parameter
>   **formal parameter** formal argument (deprecated)
>
> object declared as part of a function declaration or definition that
>   acquires a value on entry to the function, or an identifier from the
>   comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses immediately following
>   the macro name in a function-like macro definition

Thus for example in this function declaration

```
void push(struct stack *stack1,int data);
```

`stack1` and `data` are formal parameters. They require values (arguments) on entry to the function.
Take into account that because stack1 is declared as pointer to struct stack then any changes of the object pointed to by the pointer will be keep in the object after exiting the function.

Comment: so any changes made in the stack1 would be reflected in the stack1 i am passing??

Comment: @Sherlock Holmes Any changes made in the function to the object of type struct stack pointed by the parameter stack1 will be reflected in the original object.